# react-native [only Android] ScrollView within GestureDetector doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native, gesturedetector, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm building a bottom-sheet that one can swipe up/down to change its height.
I want its inner children component to be scrollable, but it doesnt work as expected.
I'm just guessing the cause of this is that any touch event like scrolling in `ScrollView` gets captured and bubbled up to `GestureDetector` so scrolling the inner content doesnt work while swiping the sheet itself works.

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {
  Extrapolate,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get('window');

type Props = {
  top: number;
  bottom: number;
  initialBottomOffset: number;
};

export const BottomSheet: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  top,
  bottom,
  initialBottomOffset,
}) => {
  const translateY = useSharedValue(0);
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const HEADER_HIGHT = useHeaderHeight();

  const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y = -SCREEN_HEIGHT + top;
  const MIN_TRANSLATE_Y = -(bottom + insets.bottom);

  const scrollTo = useCallback((destination: number) => {
    'worklet';
    translateY.value = withSpring(destination, { damping: 50 });
  }, []);

  const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });
  const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart(() => {
      context.value = { y: translateY.value };
    })
    .onUpdate(event => {
      translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
      translateY.value =
        event.translationY < 0
          ? Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y)
          : Math.min(translateY.value, MIN_TRANSLATE_Y);

      if (Math.abs(event.velocityY) > 300) {
        if (event.translationY < 0) {
          scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
        } else {
          scrollTo(MIN_TRANSLATE_Y);
        }
      }
    });

  const animatedBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const borderRadius = interpolate(
      translateY.value,
      [MAX_TRANSLATE_Y + HEADER_HIGHT, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
      [25, 0],
      Extrapolate.CLAMP,
    );

    return {
      borderRadius,
      transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollTo(MIN_TRANSLATE_Y);
  }, [bottom]);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollTo(-initialBottomOffset);
  }, [initialBottomOffset]);

  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.bottomSheetContainer, animatedBottomSheetStyle]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.handle}
          onPress={() => scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y)}
        />
        <ScrollView>{children}</ScrollView>
      </Animated.View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomSheetContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 25,
    flex: 1,
  },
  handle: {
    width: 45,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#CEDEEA',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? similar problem

Comment: @joshuaaron sorry not yet. pls let me know if you get it ;)

Answer (score 7):

It is working fine after ScrollView & Flatlist are imported
in `react-native-gasture-handler`